# Check if Series contains any element from a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm reading a large CSV file and one of the columns has below representation.

```
import pandas as pd

df['col1'] = pd.Series(
    ["37", "AWESOME House", "Yellow Cottage, 107", "14"], dtype='object'
)
```

My code uses "vectorized string methods" to return desired data in timely fashion.

**Simplified** code to illustrate some parts of logic.

```
import numpy as np

sth = np.where(
    <check condition>,
    df['col1'].str.lower(),
    df['some_other_column'].whatever()
)
```

Next I'd like to check if each value in my `Series` contains *any* element from below list.

```
check_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

So expected result (for "check condition") would be:

```
False
True
True
False
```

I tried this

```
np.where(
    np.any([x in df['col1'].str.lower() for x in check_list])
...
```

but received error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How could I solve my problem correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with joined values of list by `|` for regex `or` with `case=False` for case non sensitive search:

```
print (df['col1'].str.contains('|'.join(check_list), case=False))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Without `regex`:

```
print (df['col1'].apply(lambda x: any([i in x.lower() for i in check_list])))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

---

```
print ([any([i in x.lower() for i in check_list]) for x in df['col1']])
[False, True, True, False]
```

Comment: This works - thanks! However it uses regex therefore it slowed down my data generation by about 10% (judging by initial tests). How would you solve this **without** regex ?

Comment: I thought the `apply` method would be slow as my understanding is it returns a new DataFrame/Series which I do not really need.... Anyway I compared `apply` with `map` and Python's list comprehension (`[any(...) for x in df['col']]`) and `apply` is the fastest! Any further performance gains are welcome :-)